# Human oriented string comparison

Tags: code-golf, string

Traditionally when you compare two strings you use lexicographical comparison. That can be described by the recursive algorithm:

$$
f(x, y)=
\left\{\begin{array}[rr] \\
\mathrm{EQ} & \mathrm{if}\,\mid x\mid=0\,\mathrm{and}\,\mid y\mid=0 \\
\mathrm{GT} & \mathrm{if}\,\mid x\mid>0\,\mathrm{and}\,\mid y\mid=0 \\
\mathrm{LT} & \mathrm{if}\,\mid x\mid=0\,\mathrm{and}\,\mid y\mid>0 \\
\mathrm{GT} & \mathrm{if}\,x_0 > y_0 \\
\mathrm{LT} & \mathrm{if}\,x_0 < y_0 \\
f(\mathrm{tail}(x),\mathrm{tail}(y)) & \mathrm{if}\,x_0 = y_0
\end{array}\right.
$$

This has many advantages, however it does have some drawbacks. In particular it doesn't work like we might want it with our base 10 numerals.  For example `9` is "greater than" `852` with lexicographical comparison because its first digit is larger.

So for more human oriented sorting we can use a modified algorithm:

- Break each string into runs of consecutive digits (`0-9`) and individual non-digit characters.  For example `abc29em3jdd` -> `a b c 29 e m 3 j d d`
- Compare each of the two broken strings with lexicographical comparison treating each piece as a single symbol. Compare two individual characters as normal. When comparing two runs of digits, consider the one which is longer to be greater, otherwise compare them lexicographically. When comparing a run of digits with a individual character treat the run of digits as if it were its first digit.

This produces some pretty nice results.  `852` is greater than `9`, and `b15` is greater than `a16`.

### Task

Implement this human oriented comparison by taking two strings as input and outputting one of three distinct values. One if the two strings are equal, one if the first input is "greater" than the second and the last if the second input is "greater" than the first.

You can assume that the strings are finite and consist of only characters on the range of 32 to 127.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

### Test cases

```
"abc" "abx" => LT
"abx" "abc" => GT
"abx" "abx" => EQ
"ab" "abc" => LT
"ab" "ab10" => LT
"ab10c" "ab9x" => GT
"ab9x" "ab10c" => LT
"15x" "16b" => LT
"16b" "15x" => GT
"852" "9" => GT
"1,000" "9" => LT
"1.000" "9" => LT
"20.15.12" "20.19.12" => LT
"20.15.12" "6.99.99" => GT
"15k19" "15w12" => LT
"9w" "10" => LT
"10" "9w" => GT
"a123" "123a" => GT
"#123" "123#" => LT
"3-2" "3-1" => GT
"a000" "a0" => GT
"a001" "a0" => GT
"a000" "a1" => GT
"0xa" "0x10" => GT
"0_10" "0_4" => GT
"/" "*" => GT
```

Comment: Something's wrong with the mathjax preview on this.  If you edit the question and the preview looks wrong don't worry about it, as long as you haven't editted the mathjax itself it will look correct once you hit submit.

Comment: Just sorting a list would be shorter than outputting 3 distinct values :/

Comment: Are there any bounds on the integers contained within the string? E.g. can we assume any of the following? (a) they fit into our native integer datatype (within reason), (b) that they are under a certain specific maximal value, (c) their base 10 representation is no longer than a certain length?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Whatever default rules apply to integers apply here.

Comment: Windows Explorer, 0 bytes. Input is by creating files whose names are the strings to be sorted, output is by reading the files in the Explorer window.

Comment: So, "000" is greater than "42"?

Comment: FYI: You may have described [Natural Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order), or a variant depending on the specific rules you settled with.

Comment: shouldn't it be `"a000" < "a1"`?

Comment: @c-- No, the described algorithm first checks the length of the numbers, and then compares them lexicographically, so `000` is longer than `1`, thus it is greater.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <strike>230</strike> <strike>178</strike> 176 bytes

edit: - bytes thank to c--, -6 thanks to pan

```c
*p="1234567890";i,j;f(char*x,char*y){x[i=strcspn(x,p)]+y[j=strcspn(y,p)]?strncmp(x,y,i>j?j:i)?:i-j?:(i=strspn(x+=i,p))-strspn(y+=j,p)?:atoi(x)-atoi(y)?:f(x+i,y+i):strcmp(x,y);}
```

Returns positive for GT, negative for LT and 0 for EQ (same output as strcmp)

```c
* p = "1234567890";
i, j;
f(char * x, char * y) {
  x[i = strcspn(x, p)] + y[j = strcspn(y, p)] ? // find first digit in each string
    strncmp(x, y, i > j ? j : i) ? : // return strcmp if strings are different before first digit
    i - j? : // return longer string before the first digit
    (i = strspn(x += i, p)) - strspn(y += j, p) ? : // return longer number
    atoi(x) - atoi(y) ? : // return larger number if both have the same length
    f(x + i, y + i) : // otherwise compare the string after the numbers
    strcmp(x, y); // return strcmp if there are no digits
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZLRToMwFIYT78ZTNDUmdBRSpuAAGVfGG29MvNuMYVVciWME0JWYPYk3u9m9r6NPY1vYZJGE5LTf_5__HJJ-7ujjC6Xb7e6tSszx99cwD6E9Or9w3MuxR2DAcBokOl3ExZBjVWr0wacsLKuClnmmc5yjB6OepgdSSxKJW0aXudBrzCZplPoMRT4z08jXVbdqNkIm3Mhs77URpuIe-XG1YjpHpqq1AInwMlwbDPlyThOMgk2z98_J6fuKPWnVc1npdJWVFZC7guHrosSgC4pFibQPbcAyQZY5CEGiK5MUAm2QF0JJdDiDZ-UMgraEEyBqBjHYe7HqvgIERADe3kPgKzBpwI0C8PoOisyNpolMbRmzTEdAzFZbwnhORZ4oXJoOkDeQ9sFjZ5-xYTY5gjZpJ3nHAR7f27shtqOw7c670FXRUvuDY2ckodf1YULIP2j1wBGxbMeyVYI8e_LcL7uW54mvo3prtU33N-1mwrqDCI8lI7wxtm9l_9Z_AQ)

Previous attempt:

```c
int f(char*x,char*y){int c,i,j;for(;;){i=strcspn(x,"1234567890");j=strcspn(y,"1234567890");if(!*(x+i)&&!*(y+j)) return strcmp(x,y);if(c=strncmp(x,y,i>j?j:i))return c;if(c=atoi(x+=i)-atoi(y+=j))return c;for(;isdigit(*x);x++,y++);}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! If you're interested I have some suggestions for improving the score of your answer: 1. use K&R syntax. 2. replace the loop with recursion. 3. use `strtol(3)` to store the first non-digit. 4. use the ternary operator instead of `if`. 5. store `"1234567890"` in a variable. 5. use `x[i]` instead of `*(x+i)`.

Comment: putting it all together it's [159 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZLfboIwFMaT3Umyd2iabOFPJa0bTHDI1bKb3SzZnZoFO5klCg3ghBifZBfzxofanmalqMOMhOS0v-_rd05JP_f09Z3S3W6_ysNu__srVAtUIo4YijQ6D1K9QHqJdD7YpLN8lcagGDEvy1Oa8VhYuQdJ7-bWsu_6DobaxChH0UkWOdrEF7uYLrnMZcPIj1ym-W6QJ0wtDI9pXWHIk4VaGl6ErjkiWMhijG5pcBHgVmn1cW2wrcf8ubj8SNibks-yXKVJnOWgmhXoi3mGQBOk80xTNkqHxYIsOfBAqEpTJQyUDk-FEqpwDK-yMQSH4g2BqDFE4OhF8vQ9wMAH8OkFAleCYQ0eJYAPz1BkbhVFZCrLgMWqBkRvOSUMplTkiVJUphMsakjb4LmzzVgzgs8gwYdOznmAUxztzRBiSUzsaRPaMrrS_mDf6lXQafoQxvgfNFtgD5vEMolMqNZOtW6XbdNxxNdQnbWcpnlNUndYyz9ev4rjI_4F)

Comment: note that this fails the test case `"a000" "a0" => GT` because it doesn't compare the length of the numbers before comparing the numbers themselves, which can be fixed using `strspn(3)`

Comment: fixed version: [178 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZLRToMwFIYT78ZTNE1M2tEROgUHyLgy3nhj4t1mDKvDlThGgDnIsifxZjd7Ad9Gn8a2sMkiCcnp-c5__nMa-nlgL2-M7feHdRENRt9f_dSHdHh1bdk3I8eEHiexFyG2CLN-SVSo8DabF-ssAeWE-3mRsTxNUElS_KxXk_hEKkkCkSVsmYp6Rfg4DmKX48BFqlH16T4XQjxo8kr3Y5EHblisOCrxQMVKgEhoOal0jl05ovbE3q7e_OcCfqz4q1bM8wKxVZIXQG4L-u-LnIA2yBY51rZajyeCLFPggwgpkSx4Wi_NRCVCcAov8ykETfDHQMQEEnDUEtV9C0wQAPjwBIGrwLgG9wrAu0coPHeaJjy1ZcgThIGYrbaE4YwJPxFKKTrBsoasC54ru4Q1o-YZpGYzyTk3cMqjvG1CLYWpPWtDW1nL2h8cWUMJnbaOmKb5DxodcGga1DKocpBnR567y7bhOOJrVZ2N2qZ9TVpP2LRv2IwNqfoN9VM5PvZf)

Comment: fixed a bug with test case `"0xa" "0x10"`, [183 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZLRToMwFIYT78ZTNDUmdBRSpuAAGVfGG29MvNuMYXW4EscIMFdi9iTe7GbP4LPo09gWNllcQnLa7__Pfw5JP3f0-ZXS7Xa3qhJz-P3Vz0NoDy6vHPd66BEYMJwGiU7ncdHnWJUafRSzalVkgI9ZWFYFLfNM5zhHT0Y9Tg-kliQSt4wucqHXmI3SKPUZinxmppGvq27VbIRMuJHZ3msjTMU98uNqyXSOTFVrARLhZbg2GPLlnCYYBZtm_Z-z8_cle9GqWVnpdJmVFZArg_7bvMSgC4p5ibQPrccyQRY5CEGiK5MUAq2XF0JJdDiBF-UEgraEIyBqBjHYe7HqvgEERADeP0LgKzBqwJ0C8PYBisyNpolMbRGzTEdAzFZbwnhKRZ4oXJoOkDeQnoLHzlPGhtnkCNqkneQdB3h8b--G2I7CtjvtQldFS-0PDp2BhF7Xhwkh_6B1Ag6IZTuWrRLk2ZPn07JreZ74Oqq3Vtt0f9NuJqw7iPBYMsIbY_tW9k_-Fw)

Comment: Omitting the `return` still produces correct output under GCC due to compiler/ABI dark magic.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)! Bugfix thanks to [tsh]*

```javascript
x=>y=>((a=(g=s=>b=s.replace(/\d+/g,n=>0+n.padStart(16)))(x))>g(y))-(a<b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZJNb@IwEIbv/AqL9mAvTrBhQRuxzq3qpZdqe2NR6yROym6URLFZUqH8duqPfG2RiDXzeN55x2j@8H9cxvWxUl5RJuKasmvDwg8WQsgZzJhkYcSkX4sq57GAy9/JYpnhgoVkUfgVT34pXitItwgh2CAUZvADIQ/ynxG6xmUhFXh6AQx4dDdz6aNJwZA@PJuU7Ga5UCDmUkid72cA7Oc8iudYn80cP70csCWNJZo//k/0@fDckb5kEFlAiSNda0pc86CZ9AqarnRU041hdBuNxMSOd8Ifm5Umgcttf4oJIY71Kv8rWRGfbnxqpCYMbHh7t/WDQP@mzTd/aWBHOE8kwdkgMhpat/P4Orpam4rVmg/sbmB3kz9n7RnftUdHrZudkymhN8TWjCrSaCd9UjIZnrzawcjr96FuqfNvXclhN3ObUNa1iJXehW41Un7MRWJ2Q5ekZQ0N3HMMIgzKkzqAMnXrg8BFG5nbWshTblqkkCMYoZ3mxxT2mBmdqwa932Jhilr9iVyK7s5Z@9VJvsPREXf9D8hJWrvQZS78vMzg2/2la9kudWgG83NRZOq9BRWXUorkDd08RDSVVogEAx6rE8/tq5y9G/SLBW8xuL9E7SDUWR/qq6xUGrhWrbFrr58) Gives `-1` for `LT`, `0` for `EQ`, and `1` for `GT`.  Call as `f(a)(b)`.

Assumes the strings' integers are [safe integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding) (in this case, positive integers ≤ \$2^{53}-1\$, i.e., 16 decimal digits or less. This transforms both input strings by left padding such integers with spaces, prepending a zero, and using the native string comparison sort, which gives us the correct results. (This method, as opposed to padding with 0s, distinguishes `0` and `000`, as in such cases, the length of the string should be taken into consideration.)

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc9LDoIwEAbgvcdgNROhtCQQm9hewq2bUh5RSSFAtJwepeiKStKkk3wzfzt39VSD7m/dGJm2KOdKzFbISUgAJaAWg5C5GEhfdo3SJcTX4hjXoRHSkE4Vl1H1I7AspIgIFlHWMCFGoM45zro1Q9uUpGlrqCBQuQ5wuWyAeNigXVHvoX9yb3A1Rr3I6PdH3B/M7W/cF85SxyzLfZi5p13PBk9psiD3zYWU0r9IdjChhKWEueSl5q7ebcsI55/j3e3B@LrAy8XMbw)

Comment: Or [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc9LDoIwEAbgvcdgNROhtCQQm9hewq2bUh5RSSFAtJwepeiKStKkk3wzfzt39VSD7m/dGJm2KOdKzFbISUiAWgxCWjGQvuwapUuIr8UxrkMjpCGdKi6j6kdgGYZKWESwKGuYECNQZ4uzbs3QNiVp2hoqCFSuA1wuGyAeNmhX1Hvon9wbXI1RLzL6/RH3B3P7G/eFs9Qxy3IfZu5p17PBU5osyH1zIaX0L5IdTChhKWEueam5q3fbMsL553h3ezC@LvByMfMb) by doing just `padStart(16)`, which I think is OK?

Comment: @Arnauld Without padding start w/ 0, i think this could fail for e.g. `"000"` and `"0"`, which, as far as i understand the challenge, should be `EQ`. Very nice tip on the 72 though!!

Comment: To my understand, `000` and `0` are not equal. So we should padding using spaces as `0+n.padStart(16)`

Comment: @tsh Upon re-reading the spec, I'm not sure which is the case. fortunately the `0+` alternative is the same byte count as the `,0`, so 72 is still an accurate score under either interpretation. will wait for clarity from the test cases you proposed

Comment: @Arnauld The 70 fails `"!","0"`

Answer (score 4):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 27 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
(⍋>⍒)-⍤⌈⍥≢/↑¨¨'\d+|.'⎕S'&'¨
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=AS4A0f8o4o2LPuKNkikt4o2k4oyI4o2l4omiL@KGkcKowqgnXGQrfC4n4o6VUycmJ8Ko&f=XY5BDoAgDATvvsJbL4a0JBD7HDXh4gPg@bIUIpoQ6OxuW9JKx3kR7kJLste0mYb3sRoIdxK2MTqyWmjoECSAJZ5GEe3QQHvwldScjZlfcjN5dhKcIIxSUf706FTr6Stv0bYm96BmoH1Z2txMDw&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Tacit function that returns `0 1`, `0 0`, `1 0` for `LT`, `EQ`, `GT`, respectively. Input `f x y`.

```
              '\d+|.'⎕S'&'¨ split into numbers/others
     -⍤    ↑¨¨               left-pad splits to
       ⌈⍥≢/                    max length of inputs
(⍋>⍒)                       compare
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 95 bytes

-X bytes thanks to WheatWizzard and Conor O'Brian

```python
def f(x):a,b=[[(len(i),i)for i in re.findall('\d+|.',y)]for y in x];return(a>b)-(a<b)
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Xc1BCoJAGAXgvacYpoX_TypoLaKyK3QAlZjJGRqyGRlGUOgmbVxUd-o2aQZBq7f4eO_dnnXnTkb395lM80fjZLh6HUohiYQW1yzgaZZBJTQoDBRKY4kiShMrIql0yaoK_LycXyM_6LAYuRu5LTZWuMZqYDuOIbAtR09damPdUP3e7GurtAMJQBk_0oDQ4ZciovcDLuJkMRIXyfLPziZORvrkQNNs30_5Bg)

Comment: For 3 distinct values, you can use `(a>b)-(a<b)`. (-1, 0, 1)

Comment: This comparison should work for a lot cheaper: [`def f(x):a,b=[[[len(i),i]for i in findall('\d+|\D+',y)]for y in x];return(a>b)+2*(a<b)
from re import*`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Xc0_DoIwHIbhnVM0ONBCHagORsXJ3QMAQyv9xUZoSVMSSLyJC4N6J28jf0xMnL7hSb73_qo7dzG6fywgyZ6Ng-XmDYUEBLglW05FkqZpKTVWhKocjEUKKY1A6YKXJQ6yIrplxyigHZm0G7XNd1a6xmrMD4JELMR8L4gH1lTISqSq2lgXfmun2irtMGDsc3H2KfKHvE8I8X4gZMxWIwnJ1n92NTEbadqB5tu-n_cD)

Comment: The regular expression can be `\d+|.` as well. In fact it probably should be, as it's closer to the spec.

Comment: The 94 byte version doesn't work. Counter example: `9w` and `10`.  `10` should be larger but the regex compares `9w` with `10`, it finds them both to be the same length and then checks the first digit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 39 bytes

```
&[cmp]o*».&{[m:g/\d+|./».&{+$_//$_}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc7BDoIwDAbgV2kI4SBmrCQszggvggsBFA9KIHgAgjyZN18Mu41ITHb4@q9t2l67h1jqEbwK4sVLy7pVze7zZt6U1sdbcL74LxaY2nezIHCzWc3LMx/BcbOUK6ABIKGCOIGpIs8OVE0Hp7woIS@GZK85EMuNa7qFJOSWyPWcXFvkYL5MG0YDoCgMRQFUah6iEKTJ9pzzlezHkDOMGIagIQl/oWBS0rPb7yhpaW9bZA/2IqRFfbJ8AQ)

- `*».&{ ... }` is an anonymous function that maps its list-of-strings argument over the braced expression.
- `m:g/\d+|./` breaks a string up into a list of matches, each either a group of digits, or a single other character.
- `».&{ ... }` maps each of those lists over the braced expression.
- `+$_ // $_` tries to convert each match into a number with the `+` operator.  If that fails, the defined-or operator `//` replaces the error with the original value.
- `[ ... ]` wraps each list in an `Array`.
- `&[cmp]` is a reference to the built-in `cmp` operator, which operates on arrays of heterogeneous data types just as specified in the problem statement.  It returns one of the enumerated values `Less`, `Same`, or `More`.
- `o` composes those two functions together.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 49 bytes

```
\d+
$.&$*10$&
^
$%'¶
O`¶.*
^(.*)(¶\1)*(¶.*)*$
$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1NTsMwEIXX864RtySGmhmnqbAEvQILWFZtnJQFqtRFhRSfLAfIxcKYRkLy8/fmx8@3r5/va5xX5UdL8@H8COPWxgqbNY4wq4dpxHs7jc7iWDpbldN4kMqWuVNZA1P4@bM9t/vXtzl2PcUuQaXsF@Z6KRXCyFdeDHkS0l@zhzSJZNdBRerx0ngKkCdmznR3enbSOPGUTVDz39m5EPRo0EWCRgw6DAPph6IvB0TxNakiisUVqDee6o0g5vTImbJQawGnSJw0gk8awqctnsn@Ag) Takes newline-separated input and outputs `0`, `1` or `2` for `GT`, `LT` and `EQ` but link is to test suite that splits on tabs and translates the output to `>`, `<` or `=` for convenience. Explanation:

```
\d+
$.&$*10$&
```

Prefixes each run of digits with a run of `1`s of the same length and a `0`. This maintains lexicographical sort order when comparing numbers with non-numbers while making numbers sort by length and then lexicographically.

See below for the explanation of the rest of the program. Previous 44 byte version compared digit strings numerically rather than by length:

```
\d+
$*10
^
$%'¶
O`¶.*
^(.*)(¶\1)*(¶.*)*$
$#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1NCsIwEIXXmWuYYholZAItDqhXcKHLUtK/hQguRGhP1gP0YnFGC0Im35s3k5fX8L4/m5SZa1Sp6negLXqoQWfbZYZLXGZnoTbO5maZK8ytESe3GvQmpFvs4/l4Sk3bqaadgIvZrZR@bRkcK5cskkxo@podYDEpLFvgUqzhUARFgHvvvdD9GLzDwmFQIojF3ykdER8OeiBxxMhDGhV/iPxy/AA) Takes newline-separated input and outputs `0`, `1` or `2` for `GT`, `LT` and `EQ` but link is to test suite that splits on tabs and translates the output to `>`, `<` or `=` for convenience. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*10
```

Replace all embedded runs of digits with a run of that number of `1`s followed by a `0`. This maintains lexicographical sort order when comparing numbers with non-numbers while making numbers sort numerically.

```
^
$%'¶
```

Make a copy of the first string.

```
O`¶.*
```

Sort the modified strings lexicographically.

```
^(.*)(¶\1)*(¶.*)*$
$#2
```

Count how many strings match the first string. If both strings were equal, then they will both match. If the first string was less than the second, then it will match and the other string will not. If the first string was greater than the second, then there will not be any additional matches.

I include the previous newline in the sort string as non-empty strings are easier to process in Retina, but note that the above rule works whether or not the copy is included in the sort; with the copy, the possible results are `EEE` (all equal), `FFS` (first sorts before second), `SFF` (first sorts after second), while without the copy, the third result is `FSF`, where the first two strings are still different.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÙΣ.γd}εÐdigs»]k
```

Input as a pair of strings. Outputs `[0,1]` for \$LT\$; `[1,0]` for \$GT\$; and `[0]` for \$EQ\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Mxzi/XObU6pPbf18ISUzPTiQ7tjs///j1ZSNjQyVtJRApLKSrEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XY6xTsMwEIZfJXIXQK65S0hUT1mKWFiQKpYoqhyKqqgDQyWSDpGYmBEbCwtj2RATA1K95yH6IqnPdqCtZNn/d//vu3tYqqK87x5XKQu2z68BS1dj1um39kO0X7Om/dYvs3K@3Pzki46J23G6@Sy3T@9XE72ek7i80WvzXE@ahgUn@veU8S7LmCruGDd3zXKe2Zfb2j713oFlAcETgmsj@6ysfcDlMSbGpHCU0HeqEY3i0JB0DgeAfxL7FILAWCCFSUqSR/VESGmOH7lAacdUPigrQrcy2r6V2xbDiJwwUpYHfzywHA2pdzREl3Y7KegJD8h6Lgm1MgC1HwlTOxSmFxbPjT5jeb4D).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù            # Uniquify the (implicit) input-pair (for the EQ test cases)
 Σ           # Sort the pair by:
  .γ         #  Adjacent group the substrings by:
    d        #   Is it a (non-negative) number
   }ε        #  After the adjacent-group-by: map over each part:
     Ð       #   Triplicate the current part
      di     #   Pop one, and if it's a (non-negative) number:
        g    #    Pop another, and push its length
         s   #    Swap so the number is before the length on the stack
          »  #    Join the stack (the length & number) with newline delimiter
 ]           # Close the if-statement, map, and sort-by
  k          # Get the indices of this sorted pair into the (implicit) input-pair
             # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 41 bytes

```perl
sub{s/\d+/$&+1e9.$&/ge for@_;pop cmp pop}
```

Returns -1 for GT, 0 for EQ and 1 for LT.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJRb4IwEMef5VNcmioaC1KTGivR@bLsYcvMEt/QGEUwi0OYugxi/OysLag4ZRmB8L@7X@9/R4i87QdLgwSwD/1097U47FqTZbOFa03qcRPXWisP/HA7nNlRGIEbRCDex9TWRLLuoPnCRQTUJXSMMgn9AegvY31KNBk5qnTB3CL2VIpddXt8K2In6qbbtWkRoxYqw6iVLyE0j1HZbPw0XH7kbjfKLivQzqJsNlk6Yywu@yBd1j5j/ATdYpRYlpWv8Au7MjX/hbUtkzKTSmeludR/Yx2Tc3Gje7OxNeW5KWXfqlXBtKEdFBgkdRwTwIl4vDhqQB@GeGbnNcCrcC9SNezXIZhHeCYwhTcyJK87sieRPwtRQxgDB6ihitMMjLbvm72PqkZnJ6K4B1WjK1VyVsLdc/feUiRkKM5KNdkgolXkaOB9ZnYPoIdrHXqgv47GMHrWSaW4AlGUrR3THw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
œ-œlLɗÐƤ€ØDoṚ$ż"¹Ġ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oZN2jk3N8Tk4/POHYkkdNaw7PcMl/uHOWytE9Sod2Hlnw/3D70UkPd86weLi72x@IHzXMcQ8BEj4gwjXwUcNcHW@g8iwgT8HWTgHI14z8/z86WikxKVlJRwFIVSjF6nBFgxlgfjIaHy6PJg3hGhrA@IYGUAMt4TosK2CKoLoMTcEihmZJUL4Z2BiQMJhvYWoE4ltCZXUMDAyQ@XqofCMDPUNTPUOwFhDbEsTGkDHTs7QEIpgDsg0tIVaWwxRbloMFoB4xhNhQDvWDoZExWNbIOBEioowQUYaIGOuC7THWNYTqgboy0QDON0TjQ@Sh6g0qEkFcgwqYEwziIY4wiDeBCOiDeFpKsbEA)

Takes a list of two inputs, and returns `[[1], [2]]` for LT, `[[1, 2]]` for EQ, and `[[2], [1]]` for GT. (The test footer converts these because my brain couldn't handle checking the test cases otherwise.)

A band-aid fix to a solution that otherwise always compares digits as greater than non-digits.

```
      ÐƤ              For every prefix (largest first) of
        €             each of the inputs,
    L                 get the length of
œ-                    the multiset difference of the suffix and
  œl ɗ   ØD           the suffix with leading digits removed.
           o          Replace zeroes in either result with
            Ṛ$        corresponding elements of the other result,
              ż"¹     then zip each result with the corresponding input.
                 Ġ    Group indices, sorted by value.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 506 bytes

Modified from [@Kjetil S's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257589/110802)

---

Golfed version, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTBjpswEL3nK0aIPaUgHCnRsnvoqeqhVVeV9paiygGHRUuAGqN1hPzt6Qw2kC5RtRYi9ryZ98bMTFRaXi6NrFMoqlSKk6jU76o7HYRsoW@VNPgWCqRou1KB5z0CHYtMQ/QIx1oKnr7AiSt876XIhW4g4GUJQVGVRSXoNytS0UIQQP8rWxvwkTWxrK3iUsEeHTOhwbc0UWI1RJW9hxhCvGkIcQntkayocpC8ysVADT4lt8dEJPS@VQiAmcTR4uVuRllPH7mXIo6MQtfARGySkA7ztxg9KGhNYuajiVo9KVQnK/CtMwYPFTlCr@HsKoAiywr52t3qfBM9z9SjflqfGi4xA02wuYwlVKJV0K8AV88PKQyLHzS49f3ZjKAewXQEv94Ap8gvPycQFpFXtBPIoiXIotSCsV5qOtvkdRXJts6f7Q4Lzck2eV3R3m831hIDLED2KYqid@BMG/4H3EQh24ZsA7SJaXML3IVxjM@/mttXFtts39hmpjWubCVv2yLHJhpKiY0D2JQDQg2S19iDR1d2a30raKZ8QiwDrYDZdiPrmBetaDaPBR1ymc1jombSxJFSXTsPB/43iD9W8DN49asHD@D9eHqGp2@esUk1ncIAbEocePDugl2LRv0Ad8E97c7TDslEqkSGBjoiJ@28YY5JdLgoDJokmKzM6vIX)

```
proc increment_numbers {str} {set result ""; set idx 0; foreach match [regexp -all -inline -indices -- {\d+} $str] {set start [lindex $match 0]; set end [lindex $match 1]; append result [string range $str $idx [expr {$start - 1}]]; set num [string range $str $start $end]; append result [expr {$num + 1e9}].$num; set idx [expr {$end + 1}]}; append result [string range $str $idx end]; return $result}; proc f {x y} {set x [increment_numbers $x]; set y [increment_numbers $y]; return [string compare $x $y]}
```

Ungolfed version

```
proc increment_numbers {str} {
    set result ""
    set idx 0
    foreach match [regexp -all -inline -indices -- {\d+} $str] {
        set start [lindex $match 0]
        set end [lindex $match 1]
        append result [string range $str $idx [expr {$start - 1}]]
        set num [string range $str $start $end]
        append result [expr {$num + 1e9}].$num
        set idx [expr {$end + 1}]
    }
    append result [string range $str $idx end]
    return $result
}

proc f {x y} {
    set x [increment_numbers $x]
    set y [increment_numbers $y]
    return [string compare $x $y]
}

foreach test {
    {abc      abx        LT}
    {abx      abc        GT}
    {abx      abx        EQ}
    {ab       abc        LT}
    {ab       ab10       LT}
    {ab10c    ab9x       GT}
    {ab9x     ab10c      LT}
    {15x      16b        LT}
    {16b      15x        GT}
    {852      9          GT}
    {1,000    9          LT}
    {1.000    9          LT}
    {20.15.12 20.19.12   LT}
    {20.15.12 6.99.99    GT}
    {15k19    15w12      LT}
} {
    lassign $test x y exp
    set got [f $x $y]
    switch $got {
        -1 {set got LT}
        0 {set got EQ}
        1 {set got GT}
    }
    set status [expr {$exp eq $got ? "ok" : "NOT OK"}]
    puts [format "%-6s   x: %-8s   y: %-8s   expected: %s   got: %s" $status $x $y $exp $got]
}
```